# Applying Pythagoras to Accelerometer

Tags: android, accelerometer

I don't know the maths terminology, but from the x/y/z values of the accelerometer, I want to get a single value that represents the total/net acceleration, that ignores the direction.

Would this simply be :

```
      _________________
 a = / x^2 + y^2 + z^2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is the scalar length of the vector and that should be the formula you want.

Answer (score 1):

yes: http://programmedlessons.org/VectorLessons/vch04/vch04_8.html